# FCM notification no screen on, no heads up when in background

Tags: android

I implemented push notification.

It works find when the app is in foreground (the notification triggers OnMessageReceived method).

But, when the app is in background, there's no heads up.
And, when the phone is in sleep mode, the notification don't turns on the screen.

How can I fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you send *data*. 
Your request body should be constant *data* field. E.q.:
{
  "to": "/topics/fcm_globals",
  "data": {
    "field1": "value1",
    "field2": "value2"
  }
}

If you have Xiaomi device. Check that system not blocked you app in background.

Comment: Yes. 
Here is additional information https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server

Answer (score 1):

With FCM, you can send two types of messages to clients:

**Notification messages**, sometimes thought of as "display messages."

**Data messages**, which are handled by the client app.

As per [FCM official document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive),

[image]

**Use only data messages** if you want to receive(In `OnMessageReceived` method) and process it when your app is in background.